# parse XML with the libmxml library

Tags: c++, xml

I want to parse a XML string.
I use in the mxml library.

if this is my xml string

```
<root>
 <name1>1</name1>
 <name2>2</name2>
 <name3>3</name3>
</root>
```

Than I want to print

name1:1

name2:2

name3:3

I can't find a good documentation to iterate a simple XML.
That's the code I got so far.

```
#include <mxml.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char buffer[8192] = "<x><a>111</a><w>qqq</w><z>112</z></x>";
  mxml_node_t *tree;

  tree = mxmlLoadString(NULL, buffer,MXML_TEXT_CALLBACK);

}
```

Can anyone please help me to continue?

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i got from the documentation.
Haven't tried running it.

http://www.minixml.org/documentation.php/basics.html

```
mxml_node_t *node;

for (node = mxmlWalkNext(tree, tree, MXML_DESCEND_FIRST);
     node != NULL;
     node = mxmlWalkNext(node, tree, MXML_DESCEND_FIRST)) {

   cout << node->mxmlGetElement(node) << ":" << mxmlGetText(node) << endl;
}
```

Comment: ./mxml-2.7/mxml.h: In function ‘int main()’:
./mxml-2.7/mxml.h:226: error: too few arguments to function ‘const char* mxmlGetText(mxml_node_t*, int*)’
xml.cpp:42: error: at this point in file